# Show that n^2 is not O(n*log(n))?

Tags: big-o, proof

Using only the definition of O()?

Comment: Should this perhaps go on the Mathematica site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove by contradiction. Assume that `n^2` **is**  `O(n*log(n))`. Which means by definition there is a finite and non variable real number `c`  such that

```
n^2 <= c * n * log(n)
```

for every n bigger than some finite number `n0`.

Then you arrive to the point when `c >= n /log(n)`, and you derive that as `n -> INF`, `c >= INF` which is obviously impossible.

And you conclude `n^2` **is not**  `O(n*log(n))`

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate the limit of

```
  (n * log(n)) / (n ^ 2) =
= log(n) / n =
= 0 if n approaches infinity.
```

because `log(n)` grows slower than `n`.

Comment: I would give this a +1, except that the question really deserves a -1.

Comment: this is not a big-o proof...

Comment: @UmNyobe Then what is this?

Comment: I mean this is not a formal proof, ie it doesnt use the definition of Big-O as the OP requested.